# Как сравнить два OutputSream'a, понять что содержимое эквивалентно?

Tags: java, тестирование, сравнение, java-output-stream

Пишу UT и столкнулся с тем, что нужно сравнить expected и actual(полученный в ходе выполнения теста) потоки `OutputStream`. Как это лучше сделать, желательно задействовав меньше кода?

Comment: ИМХО, но у тебя в теории вообще не должно быть желания сравнивать OuputStream'ы, т.к. они для этого вообще не предназначены. Другое дело, что у тебя вполне может быть желание получить "содержимое" этих OutputStream'ов и сравнить их. Потому вопрос сводиться к тому, как правильно читать "содержимое" OutputStream'ов. А тут уже всё зависит от конкретной реализации.

Comment: @Темкатоже в моем контексте речь идет о стримах, полученных из HttpServletResponse. Один из них, получен после прохождения теста, второй - actual.

Answer (score 2):

`OutputStream` - это интерфейс, т.е. для тестирования нужно использоавть отдельный класс имплементирующий этот интерфейс.

> Например `ByteArrayOutputStream`, используется для того чтобы ложить
>   туда данные, а затем извлекать данные из него с помощью
>   `toByteArray()`. Это не будет проверкой того, как оно записывается в
>   поток (по одному байту за раз или в виде большого буфера), но, как
>   правило, вам все равно это не нужно.

---

Вот простой код, который выполняет тестирование `System.out`:

```
public class SysOutTest {

    private final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    @Before
    public void before() {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(baos));
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        System.setOut(null);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.print("привет!");
        assertEquals("привет!", baos.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: [Что означает если ответ "принят"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
byte[] a = {1, 2, 3};
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
outputStream1.write(a);

byte[] b = {1, 2, 3};
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
outputStream2.write(b);

System.out.println(Arrays.equals(outputStream1.toByteArray(), 
           outputStream2.toByteArray()));
```

Дальше остается только вызвать нужный assert в тесте:

```
assertTrue(Arrays.equals(outputStream1.toByteArray(), 
           outputStream2.toByteArray()));
```

Или, как правильно написали в другом ответе, можно не доставать массив байтов.

Comment: В `java` `equals()` проверяет на равенство или тождественность?

Comment: Равенство проверяется оператором "==" (у объекных типов сравниваются ссылки, под исключение попадают и массивы).
Тождественность методом equals() - по отношению к объектам (сравнение внутренних данных).
В общем содержимое массивов нельзя оператором "==" сравнивать.

Comment: То есть `a.equals(b) == true` в вашем примере?

Comment: Нет, массивы нельзя через equals() сравнивать. Либо перебором, сравнивая каждый элемент отдельно, либо используя утильные классы, к прим. Arrays. Ради интереса можете заглянуть в этот класс и посмотреть, как там equals реализован.

Comment: А если на месте a и b будут экземпляры одного класса с одинаковым набором полей- что выдает equals в этом случае?

Comment: Если в полях двух экземпляров будут идентичные значения, то выдаст true. Ну и еще зависит, как equals в этом классе реализован.